# SharedPreferences being reset after force close

Tags: java, android, save, android-sharedpreferences

I have been able to successfully implement Shared Preferences into my application but I have ran into a problem with the data being reset/deleted if I kill the application through a task manager.

I am using a static method for saving, that way I only need the method once and can call it everywhere within my app.

```
protected static synchronized void save(Context cntx){
    SharedPreferences preferences2 = cntx.getSharedPreferences("BluRealms", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences2.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("level", Stats.level);
    editor.commit();
}
```

As soon as I kill my app all of my data gets set back to the default settings in my SharedPreferences save method.

I also did some searching and found a few posts that say adding android:persistent="true" into the  of the manifest file would fix the problem, yet the data is still reset even with this.

---

**Edit:** Well I think I found a bit of information on my problem. This Issue highlights a problem with Samsung Galaxy S phones not saving SharedPreferences properly, which is the device I am testing on. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14359 - especially **comment 6**

Any more information on this would be great!

Comment: Do you call this method from the onPause or onDestroy?

Comment: Are you using `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`any where in your application?

Comment: @jaisonDavis - I am calling this from onPause() in all of my methods, but I do have a call in one onDestroy() since onPause doesnt get called on some activity closes.

Comment: @Lalit - No I am only using getSharedPreferences(), how can getDefaultSharedPreferences help? I have read that some devices don't work properly with getDefaultSharedPreferences()

Comment: It seems to me the problem is with the Stats.level, have you tried sending the level as an argument?

Comment: what would be the benefits of sending an integer variable as an argument, instead of a direct call to the static variable?

Comment: Is this the level that is getting changed when you get your application killed?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple variables, all are like level though, they all get saved, normally that is when the application is closed properly. For some reason when I hit the home key and force close the app through a task killer, all of the data gets reset, but the application resumes back on the activity i hit home key on, like I never killed the app at all.

Comment: did you find some fix for this issue related to samsung galaxy s ? thanks.

Comment: It turns out this can also be caused by invalid preference keys, such as keys containing newlines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385132/sharedpreferences-in-android-not-persisted-to-disk-when-key-contains-newline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I was able to solve this by removing the "protected static" from my save method.

Instead of calling a global save method, I simply placed the save method in each class that would need to save and then only call the save method in the onPause() and onDestroy() methods.

I noticed that if I called save() too many times within a class that also seemed to erase my SharedPreferences when I closed the app.

**TIP:**

> Do not use static methods for getting or setting shared preferences

Comment: Yaa it worked for me. One more thing i found is that even the database is getting cleared while using static methods for getting shared preferences, i know it kind of wired but it was happening. so lesson of the day is to not use static methods for getting shared preferences :)

Comment: I'm already using like this, but same problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case remove the tag android: allowBackup = "true" from my manifest and this solves my problem