# how to clear my SharedPreferences when my app is killed through task manager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using SharedPreferences to save the state of my CheckBox items in my ListView so that I don't lose the checked state when switching from FragmentActivity A to FragmentActivity B then back to FragmentActivity A. I want to clear my SharedPreferences if user exits the app.

My SharedPreferences is initialized in my BaseAdapter class like this:

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

I override onBackPressed() method in my FragmentActivity A and call

```
MyBaseAdapter.editor.clear().commit();
```

I am only able to clear my SharedPreferences if user exits the app by clicking the back button but if user kills the app through the task manager while the app is running, SharedPreferences is not cleared. So, when user opens the app again, the CheckBox items in my ListView are checked which should not be. The CheckBox items in my ListView should be unchecked when user opens the app. The problem is how do I clear my SharedPreferences if my app is killed by the user through task manager while the app is active or running?

I tried overriding onStop() method on my FragmentActivity A and call

```
MyBaseAdapter.editor.clear().commit();
```

but my SharedPreferences are deleted when I navigate from FragmentActivity A to FragmentActivity B. I don't want to lose the state of my CheckBox items in my ListView from FragmentActivity A when I switch between FragmentActivity A to FragmentActivity B and vice versa.

Comment: is your app active at the time of killing the app from TaskManager

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480871/sharedpreferences-being-reset-after-force-close

Comment: If you don't want the values to be persisted, why are you using SharedPreferences?  If your app is killed, you cannot clear them.

Comment: Yes. The app is active at the time of killing the app through task manager. I'm using SharedPreferences to save the state of my CheckBox items in my ListView when switching from Activity A to Activity B then back to Activity A.

Comment: My question stands.  If you don't want to save the values, why are you using SharedPreferences?

Comment: As a complement to @Simon comment, if you need to have some values persisted only during a session, then you can store them in some static variables for example. Or, you may still use SharedPreferences, but every time on application start up, clear the SharedPreferences.

Comment: Yes, I only need the values saved when the app is active. Clearing my SharedPreferences in onCreate() method did not work. The app crashes and causes an error. My SharedPreferences is initialized in my InfoTechAdapter.class extends BaseAdapter which generates the CheckBox items of my ListView.
 private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
 
then in my onCreate() method I call InfoTechAdapter.editor.clear().commit();

Comment: One last try, then I'm out of here since you are not answering my question.  Why are you using SharedPrerences?  From everything you have said, it is the wrong choice.

Comment: I did answer your question. I'm using SharedPreferences to save the state of my CheckBox items in my ListView when switching from Activity A to Activity B then back to Activity A. I don't claim to be good at this, and you may be right that using SharedPreferences is not a good choice for this method that I want to achieve. It would be great if you could share your wisdom & tell me what then should I use & how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: OK, you haven't answered my question which was "why", not "what for".  I am going to guess that you do not want to save any values from one instance of your app to another.  http://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/singletons-in-android/ This is probably easiest.  Personally, I would use a list of checkboxes shared between the fragments or a parallel array of booleans to retain their check states although this is harder to manage.

Comment: I see. Sorry about that. Using SharedPreferences is the only way I know and I guess it is the most common practice of developers when storing persistent values. My head hurts. I can't comprehend the information I just read in your link. @_@

Comment: @Marss try using the static variables shown in my answer, it will really help you

Comment: @Marss could you accept an answer, if one worked for you?

Comment: @Marss to accept an answer, click the green check box to it's left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you be using shared preferences if you want to clear them on your app launch?

Shared Preferences are a way to store small preferences and read them later, for things such as settings.

**You could just define static variables in your activities and read them in your other ones.** If you do want to clear the shared preferences, you should do it on the boot-up after your app is killed.
Example of static variables:

```
public static int i;
if(I want to set a value){
i = 1;
}
```

To access this in another activity:

```
if(MainActivity.i == 1){
//do something
}
```

Comment: It is working now. I initialized SharedPreferences in my FragmentActivity class instead of initializing it from my BaseAdapter class and I declared it as public static SharedPreferences so that I can just use it from my BaseAdapter class. I also included a condition in my onCreate method if(Bundle==null), then clear my SharedPreferences so that it will delete my SharedPreferences when user opens the app.

Comment: I am also storing my data in a variable but there is a problem that when the Android silently kills the app to reclaim some memory, then how can i refetch my data because if i were using shared prefrences then my problem will get solved.

Answer (score 1):

clear those on app launch. same thing to me.

Comment: I get this error if I call MyBaseAdapter.editor.clear().commit(); in my onCreate() method 09-28 19:24:32.641: E/AndroidRuntime(6409): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.usjr.sss/com.usjr.sss.activity.CourseFragmentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how are you setting your values into `SharedPreferences` or why are you declaring it static, as it's already called `Shared` and meant to, but what i usually do to set values is something like that :

```
Integer myValue=0;//some int value
SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SomeFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor ed = sp.edit();
    ed.putInt("myKey", myValue);
    ed.commit();
```

And to read it back :

```
SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SomeFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Integer myValue= sp.getString("myKey", null);
```

To simply clear values in the file "SomeFileName" :

```
SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SomeFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor ed = sp.edit();
            ed.clear().commit();
```

So make sure to clear the `SharedPreferences` file the proper way in `onCreate()` and i guess it will work.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. I declared it as static so that I can access it through my other classes.

Comment: Note that when you set a value in `SharedPreferences` you can access it from any other activity without having to declare it static

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clear  `SharedPreferences`  when my app is killed through `task manager`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programatically clear the shared preferences content- You can clear your app data from the application manager which is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

If the SharedPreferences Data is in a different app... i dont see how you could reach it.
first of all you can solve your issue by using SQL,then you can access your DB in any activity without any issues.

second if you dont want to kill variable while the program is running but kill them when its exited then just dont finish the activity you wont lose your variables.

you could also make the activity SingleInstance which is sort of a SingleTone

if you must and thats how you want to work... create an SQL list and clear it on onDestroy() in the main screen

but I would recommend you read about Shared Preferences and when to use them... because there doesnt seem to be any need...

Comment: I don't have another app. My SharedPreferences is initialized in my BaseAdapter class like this:  private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor; then i override onBackPressed() method in my FragmentActivity class and call MyBaseAdapter.editor.clear().commit(); I am only able to clear my SharedPreferences if user exits the app by clicking the back button but if user kills the app through the task manager while the app is running, SharedPreferences is not cleared. So, when user opens the app again, the CheckBox items in my ListView are checked.

Comment: Im sorry was typing fast... app  = activity:)

Comment: in that case did you try overriding onDestroy?

Comment: I did. onDestroy() method is not called if user kills the app through task manager while the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear your values in onDestroy and onStop method

```
override fun onStop() {
    //clear data here before super
    super.onStop()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    //clear data here before super
    super.onDestroy()
}
```