# SharedPreferences in Android not persisted to disk when key contains newline

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In Android, I'd like to write `SharedPreferences` key-value pairs where the keys are Base64 strings.

```
// get a SharedPreferences instance
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("some-name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// generate the base64 key
String someKey = new String(Base64.encode("some-key".getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.URL_SAFE), "UTF-8");
// write the value for the generated key
prefs.edit().putBoolean(someKey, true).commit();
```

In the last line, the call to commit returns `true`. So this key-value pair should have been saved successfully.

When I close and destroy the `Activity` where this piece of code was used and then re-create the `Activity` (running this code again), the specified value is returned for the key that we used.

But it turns out that, when I destroy the whole application/process (e.g. using "Force stop" in app settings), the value for our key is lost on the next launch of the `Activity`.

When I don't use `Base64.URL_SAFE` but `Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP` as the flags for the Base64 encoding, it works fine.

So this problem has been caused by the newlines at the end of the Base64 keys. Keys like `abc` can be written without any problems. But when the key is `abc\n`, it fails.

The problem is that it appears to work without problems first, returning `true` on `commit()` and returning the correct preference value on subsequent calls. But when the whole application is destroyed and re-started, the value has not been persisted.

Is this intended behaviour? A bug? Does the documentation say anything about valid key names?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual `shared_prefs/` XML file to see what gets stored?

Comment: is it a typo that your using `"some-key"` string value instead of the `some-key` variable value in the last line ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took a look at GrepCode and see that the operations will be the following (I do not mention useless ones) :

1. android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.commit()
2. **android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.commitToMemory()**
3. android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.queueDiskWrite(MemoryCommitResult,Runnable)

   3.1. XmlUtils.writeMapXml(Map, OutputStream)

   3.2. XmlUtils.writeMapXml(Map, String, XmlSerializer)

   3.3. **XmlUtils.writeValueXml(Object v, String name, XmlSerializer ser)**

---

### First : how your data are converted ?

The method `XmlUtils.writeValueXml` writes the Object value in a XML tag with the attribute `name` set to the String value. This String value contains *exactly* the value you specified at the SharedPreference's name.

(And I confirmed this by doing a step-by-step debug with your piece of code).

The XML will be with an **unescaped** line break character. Actually, the XmlSerializer instance is a FastXmlSerializer instance and it does not escape the `\n` character (see the link for this class at the end if you want to read the source code)

Interesting piece of code :

```
writeValueXml(Object v, String name, XmlSerializer out) {
    // -- "useless" code skipped
    out.startTag(null, typeStr);
    if (name != null) {
        out.attribute(null, "name", name);
    }
    out.attribute(null, "value", v.toString());
    out.endTag(null, typeStr);
    // -- "useless" code skipped
}
```

### Second : why the result is true ?

The commit method has the following code :

```
public boolean commit() {
    MemoryCommitResult mcr = commitToMemory();
    SharedPreferencesImpl.this.enqueueDiskWrite(
        mcr, null /* sync write on this thread okay */);
    try {
        mcr.writtenToDiskLatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return false;
    }
    notifyListeners(mcr);
    return mcr.writeToDiskResult;
}
```

So it returns the `mcr.writeToDiskResult` which is set in the `SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(MemoryCommitResult)` method. Interesting piece of code :

```
writeToFile(MemoryCommitResult mcr) {
    // -- "useless" code skipped
    try {
        FileOutputStream str = createFileOutputStream(mFile);
        if (str == null) {
            mcr.setDiskWriteResult(false);
            return;
        }
        XmlUtils.writeMapXml(mcr.mapToWriteToDisk, str);
        FileUtils.sync(str);
        str.close();
        ContextImpl.setFilePermissionsFromMode(mFile.getPath(), mMode, 0);
        try {
            final StructStat stat = Libcore.os.stat(mFile.getPath());
            synchronized (this) {
                mStatTimestamp = stat.st_mtime;
                mStatSize = stat.st_size;
            }
        } catch (ErrnoException e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
        // Writing was successful, delete the backup file if there is one.
        mBackupFile.delete();
        mcr.setDiskWriteResult(true);
        return;
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "writeToFile: Got exception:", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "writeToFile: Got exception:", e);
    }
    // -- "useless" code skipped
}
```

As we see at the previous point : the XML writing is "ok" (do not throw anything, do not fails), so the sync in the file will be too (just a copy of a Stream in another one, nothing checks the XML content here !).

Currently : your key was converted to (badly formatted) XML and correctly wrote in a File. The result of the whole operation is `true` as everything went OK. Your changes are comitted to the disk **and in the memory**.

### Third and last : why do I get back the correct value the first time and a bad one the second time

Take a quick look to what happen when we commit the changes to memory in `SharedPreferences.Editor.commitToMemory(...)` method (interesting part only... :)):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : mModified.entrySet()) {
    String k = e.getKey();
    Object v = e.getValue();
    if (v == this) {  // magic value for a removal mutation
        if (!mMap.containsKey(k)) {
            continue;
        }
        mMap.remove(k);
    } else {
        boolean isSame = false;
        if (mMap.containsKey(k)) {
            Object existingValue = mMap.get(k);
            if (existingValue != null && existingValue.equals(v)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        mMap.put(k, v);
    }

    mcr.changesMade = true;
    if (hasListeners) {
        mcr.keysModified.add(k);
    }
}
```

Important point : the changes are commited to the `mMap` attribute.

Then, take a quick look to how we get back a value :

```
public boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue) {
    synchronized (this) {
        awaitLoadedLocked();
        Boolean v = (Boolean)mMap.get(key);
        return v != null ? v : defValue;
    }
}
```

We are taking back the key from `mMap` (no reading of the value in the file for now). So we have the correct value for this time :)

When you reload your application, you will load the data back from the disk, and so the `SharedPreferencesImpl` constructor will be called, and it will call the `SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDiskLocked()` method. This method will read the file content and load it in the `mMap` attribute (I let you see the code by yourself, link provided at the end).

A step-by-step debug shown me that the `abc\n` was written as `abc` (with a whitespace character). So, when you will try to get it back, you will never succeed.

---

To finish, thank you to @CommonsWare to give me a hint about the file content in the comment :)

**Links**

[XmlUtils](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/internal/util/XmlUtils.java)

[FastXmlSerializer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/internal/util/FastXmlSerializer.java)

[SharedPreferencesImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java)

[SharedPreferencesImpl.EditorImpl.commit()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#SharedPreferencesImpl.EditorImpl.commit%28%29)

[SharedPreferencesImpl.EditorImpl.commitToMemory()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#SharedPreferencesImpl.EditorImpl.commitToMemory%28%29)

[SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(MemoryCommitResult, Runnable)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite%28android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.MemoryCommitResult%2Cjava.lang.Runnable%29)

[SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(MemoryCommitResult)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile%28android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.MemoryCommitResult%29)

[SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDiskLocked()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDiskLocked%28%29)

Comment: Wow, well done! Thank you so much! So it appears this is a bug in the Android classes, right? The key should probably be escaped *before* writing it to XML so that the same format is used as for reading later.

Comment: Yeah it seems like a bug. They should tell us in the doc if special chars are not allowed. Maybe "FastXmlSerializer" is too fast making too mmuch checks :) Happy to help ;)